# javascript function not pulling information from API

Tags: javascript

the function below is not pulling the images from the API. I have double checked everything and make sure there were no error and it is matching the names from the index.html file but still it keeps giving me an error message.

```
    (function(){
        'use strict';

        $(document).ready(function(){

          $('#getDogButton').click(function(){
            $.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random", function (data) {

              console.log(data);

              const dogUrl = data.message;

              $('#dogDisplayImage').attr('src', dogUrl);

            });
          });


        })

      })();

   the below error message it what I keep seeing when inspecting the console.


ReferenceError: $ is not definedsite.js:4:5
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/site.js:4
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/site.js:21
```

Comment: Looks like you didnt include the jQuery js library (or whatever framework you are using) file in the page, for example `<script type="jquery.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're importing jQuery correctly - place this in your HTML file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```